# I'm trying to loop a basic userInput script in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, user-input

I was in the middle for a basic race selection input.

```
userInput = input
print ('I choose a(n)', userInput)
if userInput is ('Human'):
    input ('I like Humans, help that I am one')    
if userInput is ('Orc'):
    print ('Hate orcs, I dont like green :(')
if userInput is ('Android'):
    print ('Robots are cool, so by theory Androids are too')
else:
    print ('Try Again')
```

but the output is weird...

```
I choose a(n) <built-in function input>

Try Again
```

See the problem with the script? I think it does not wait for the input and since there is no input, its just says 'Try Again', but I am not totally sure on how to fix that.
    This is probably an easy fix, but I honestly don't know :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
userInput = input()
```

That is `input()` is a function call

Comment: @Samuel Quansah if my answer resolved your issue please accept it.